# How can I count the number of records with a weight property

Tags: sql, mysql, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group

I have these two tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE `papers` (
      `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Paperti` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Tow` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    INSERT INTO `papers` VALUES ('1', 'ti1', 'Article');
    INSERT INTO `papers` VALUES ('2', 'ti2', 'Conference');
    INSERT INTO `papers` VALUES ('3', 'ti3', 'Letter');
    INSERT INTO `papers` VALUES ('4', 'ti4', 'Article');
    INSERT INTO `papers` VALUES ('5', 'ti4', 'Letter');

    CREATE TABLE `typeofwwork` (
      `rec` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `tow` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `weight` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    
    INSERT INTO `typeofwwork` VALUES ('1', 'Letter', '5');
    INSERT INTO `typeofwwork` VALUES ('2', 'Article', '1');
    INSERT INTO `typeofwwork` VALUES ('3', 'Conference', '4');
```

Now you see I have a weight of the typeofworks.
I would like to count the numbers of each type of works for every paper, but when I have counted a lower weighted typeofwork for that paper, I should not count the higher weighted typeofwork.

I tried this but that is not correct.

```
    SELECT Paperti,a.tow,min(b.weight),count(*) from papers a JOIN typeofwork b on a.Tow=b.tow  GROUP BY a.Paperti;
```

The desired result should be:

```
PaperTI  Count  ToW
 ti1      1    Article
 ti2      1    Conference
 ti3      1    Letter
 ti4      1    Article       ... because Article-weight is lower than Letter-weight
```

and this should be the second result:

```
          2    Article
          1    Conference
          1    Letter
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can join the two tables and prioritize the type of work of each paper with `row_number`. The rest is just aggregation:

```
select tow, count(*) cnt
from (
    select p.tow,
        row_number() over(partition by p.paperti order by t.weight, t.rec) rn
    from papers p
    inner join typeofwwork t on t.tow = p.tow
) p
where rn = 1
group by tow
```

Note the additional sort criteria on `t.rec` in the windowing clause: it is there to break potential weight ties in a deterministic way.

Comment: GREAT! THANKS a lot! I learned again a lot.

Comment: Dear @GMB: I have now this part from your solution: `row_number() over(partition by p.mykey order by t.wei desc, t.recid) rn` but I would like to `limit t.wei < 21` only. How can I do that in this over by?

Comment: I found the solution: I have to add the restriciton in the `inner join`